# Is it a bug or feature?

Tags: qt4, pyqt

Here is a test script:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Form(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        layout = QtGui.QFormLayout(self)
        for i in range(5):
            widget = QtGui.QLineEdit()
            widget.setObjectName('line_edit_%i' % i)
            layout.addRow(QtGui.QLabel('label_%i' % i), widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

def onFocusChanged(old, new):
    print('onFocusChanged: old = %s, new = %s' % (old and old.objectName() or None , new and new.objectName() or None))

app.focusChanged.connect(onFocusChanged)

mainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow(None)
mdiArea = QtGui.QMdiArea()
mdiArea.setDocumentMode(True)
mainWindow.setCentralWidget(mdiArea)
subWindow = QtGui.QMdiSubWindow()
subWindow.setWidget(Form(None))
mdiArea.addSubWindow(subWindow)
mainWindow.show()

app.exec_()
```

The issue is that when i double click constantly on subwindow title to maximize it and restore it back, the focus switches to the next widget in the subwindow.

I made a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L26GqIBkQW8

Is this a bug?

Comment: You should mention what operating system you're testing this on. It could be OS-specific.

Comment: @Insilico. From the video, the OS is Linux (specifically, ubuntu with kde). I see the same problem on Linux (PyQt 4.9.0, Qt 4.8.0), and also on Win XP (PyQt 4.8.5, Qt 4.7.3).

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks. i submitted a bug: https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-23515

Comment: PySide 1.0.9 and PyQt 4.9.1 on Windows 7 - same problem.